# How to extract text from powerpoint text boxes, in their order within the presentation using python-pptx.

Tags: python, text, powerpoint, python-pptx

My PowerPoint slide consists of text boxes, sometimes inside group shapes. When extracting data from these, the text isn't extracted in an order.
Sometimes the textbox at the end of the ppt is extracted first and sometimes the ones in the middle and so on.

The following code gets text from textboxes and handles group objects too.

```
for eachfile in files:    
    prs = Presentation(eachfile)
    textrun=[]
    # ---Only on text-boxes outside group elements---
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if hasattr(shape, "text"):
                print(shape.text)
                textrun.append(shape.text)

        # ---Only operate on group shapes---
        group_shapes = [shp for shp in slide.shapes 
                        if shp.shape_type ==MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP]
        for group_shape in group_shapes:
            for shape in group_shape.shapes:
                if shape.has_text_frame:
                    print(shape.text)
                    textrun.append(shape.text)
    new_list=" ".join(textrun)
    text_list.append(new_list)

print(text_list)
```

I would like to filter some of the data extracted based on their order of appearance in the slide.
On what basis does the function decide the order?
What should be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Your routine will pick up the text in index order (or to put it differently, in Z-order, where later items sit above/cover earlier ones).  You need to define what you mean by "order of appearance".  Do you mean top to bottom?  Left to right?  Animation order?

Comment: Yes . Order of appearance is what I meant. Top to bottom to be precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve's comment is quite right; the shapes returned by:

```
for shape in slide.shapes:
    ...
```

Are in document order *of the underlying XML*, which is also what establishes *z-order*. Z-order is the "stacking" order, as if each shape was on a separate transparent sheet (layer), with the first returned shape on the bottom and each subsequent shape added to the top of the stack (and overlapping any beneath it).

I think what you're after here is something like left-to-right, top-to-bottom. You'll need to write your own code to sort the shapes in this order, using `shape.left` and `shape.top`.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
def iter_textframed_shapes(shapes):
    """Generate shape objects in *shapes* that can contain text.

    Shape objects are generated in document order (z-order), bottom to top.
    """
    for shape in shapes:
        # ---recurse on group shapes---
        if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP:
            group_shape = shape
            for shape in iter_textframed_shapes(group_shape.shapes):
                yield shape
            continue

        # ---otherwise, treat shape as a "leaf" shape---
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            yield shape

textable_shapes = list(iter_textframed_shapes(slide.shapes))
ordered_textable_shapes = sorted(
    textable_shapes, key=lambda shape: (shape.top, shape.left)
)

for shape in ordered_textable_shapes:
    print(shape.text)
```

Comment: By the iterable "shapes", do you mean slide.shapes or a list containing all the shapes as per my requirement ( having text shapes).

Comment: As long as it's iterable and contains shape objects, it can be whatever you want. You could use `Slide.shapes` directly, use a list, or use an iterator you wrote to select only the shapes you want (like text-boxes in this case perhaps).

Comment: I do this stuff in VBA, but if I'm interpreting your original code correctly, it'll work on the shapes that have text. That's a start, but then you'd need to add the shapes to an array or collection and sort it on .Top or .Left properties of each shape (or both) to get them in top to bottom/left to right order.

Comment: I've elaborated my example, perhaps that makes it clearer what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @scanny Upvoted the answer the moment I got a chance to implement your work. This has solved my problem. Also, could you throw light on the concept of  a "leaf" shape?

Comment: Well, a group shape contains other shapes, so it's a "container" shape. All other shapes are "leaf" shapes. The terminology comes from hierarchical data structures, in particular _trees_, where each node can either "contain" or point to other nodes, or it can be the end of a "branch" so to speak, hence the term :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)  The usage here is only partly apt, hence the quotes.